# ASUS X570-PLUS (WIFI) and Samsung 850 EVO SSD, forced to use CSM and Secure Boot not working

Tags: ssd, secure-boot, asus, windows-11-upgrade

New build with an ASUS X570-PLUS and an older Samsung 850 EVO SSD. The drive is not detected by the motherboard unless I enable CSM. Safe Boot is enabled in BIOS but Windows is showing it as disabled. The firmware of the drive is current.

I am trying to install Windows 11 and this has been holding me up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: SysInfo Screenshot]

It is formatted as MBR.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all partitions on the drive? The only reason I can think that the drive would not show unless CSM was enabled, is due to the fact, it was formatted as MBR instead of GPT.

Comment: So convert it to GPT. Windows 11 does not support MBR.

Answer (score 2):

Solution thanks to Ramhound leading me in the right direction.

I was able to resolve the issue by running `mbr2gpt.exe /convert /allowFullOS` within the command line with admin access. Windows 11 is now installed!

I followed several other routes at first, this is what worked for me. I then disabled CSM and booted as normal.